# Trying to start nc listener via torify?

Tags: tor, netcat

Trying to start nc listener via torify:

torify nc -lvnp 4444

get response: local listen fuxored: Operation not permitted

I then tried to add: -q -1 and got same response?

Comment: That port is either already in use or you just need to prepend a `sudo`.

Comment: I tried: sudo torify -lvnp 4444 and same result.

Then I ran: netstat -na | grep 4444 and nothing is using the port?

Comment: Try using another port along with `sudo`, for example `43594`.

Comment: Really stumped here. Tried multi ports..ran as root. Googled the word "fuxored" and had to laugh at the urban dictionary definition of that one! I am running in a vm and not sure if this is why I can't establish the listener? I switched network adaptor to bridged and still same response.

Comment: That you are running in a virtual machine is very relevant here, you should've mentioned it! What VM software?

Comment: Apologies..my bad. Using Oracle VM 6.1.16-140961-win

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using a virtual machine, we need to "forward" the ports in the VirtualBox control panel:

1. Ensure your virtual machine is turned off.
2. Right click your virtual machine and press Settings: [image]
3. Select the Network pane, select your adapter, and click Port Forwarding.
4. Add a new rule with the green `+` button. You don't need to fill in IP addresses. The `guest port` should be the port number you're trying to listen to on the guest OS and the `host port` is what it should map to on the host.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Yes! That worked. Thank you! You rock...much appreciated

Comment: @tesla6699 If my answer helped, please mark it as accepted.